# Understanding the relationship between $P=F/A$ in brain ventricles

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, biology

Humans have a hollow space (see the colored part in the diagram below) inside our brain where cerebrospinal fluid is produced and circulated.

[image: Diagram of a brain]

A disease exists called "normal pressure hydrocephalus" in which this space is enlarged, but pressure remains the same. I recall reading a paper in which they describe that as $P=F/A$, even though the pressure is the same, the force exerted is greater. My question is: What force and what implications does it have? Do they mean that the ventricles are exerting more force on the brain because it is doing so over an increased area?

Comment: Tip: Consider to upload image using imgur.com to avoid link rot.

Comment: In the image you link, which part is the hollow space you refer to?

Comment: The colored parts. It looks a bit weird, it's split up in different part. The pink one is where it is produced and then is circulates down to the blue one.

Comment: What do you want to know when you say "what implications does it have?".

Comment: I'm wondering where this force is being exerted. Come to think of it, with the same pressure but increased area (as the ventricles get bigger) this would actually mean that the force is lower wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It is observed that when stress is applied on a substance a strain is produce. Now when a fluid applies force then the it is called hydraulic stress ($F/A$) and the strain that occurs is called hydraulic strain ($\Delta V/V_0$, $V_0$ being the initial volume). Now

$$\frac {\Delta V}{V_0} = B  \frac {F'}{A_0} $$

Assuming that bulk modulus ($B$) of brain is constant and since the pressure almost remains constant. 
$$ \frac {F_0}{A_0} =  \frac {F'}{A'}$$
$$\varepsilon = F' = F_0 \frac {A'}{A_0}$$

Now since final area increases therefore this increases the force and this increase in force causes more strain($\varepsilon$)on the surrounding brain tissue.

Now the Wikipedia page on [this topic states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_pressure_hydrocephalus):

> As the fluid builds up, it causes the ventricles to enlarge and the pressure inside the head to increase, **compressing surrounding brain tissue** and leading to neurological complications.

Which is consistent with what we have found theoretically.